# Converting Python functions with multiple statements to lambdas

Tags: python, function, lambda, y-combinator

I'm completely new to Python and I was given a task to rewrite two Python functions using an Y combinator. To this end, I have to transform them into lambdas first, and here's the problem - they both have multiple statements and I'm having troubles with making them lambda compatible. I've been reading about using tuples or lists, but that doesn't seem to be working in my case.

```
def count(word_list, stopwords, wordfreqs):
    if word_list == []:
        return
    else:
        word = word_list[0]
        if word not in stopwords:
            if word in wordfreqs:
                wordfreqs[word] += 1
            else:
                wordfreqs[word] = 1
        count(word_list[1:], stopwords, wordfreqs)

def wf_print(wordfreq):
    if wordfreq == []:
        return
    else:
        (w, c) = wordfreq[0]
        print(w, '-', c)
        wf_print(wordfreq[1:])
```

For instance, I tried to write the last function as the following lambda:

```
wf_print = (lambda wordfreq:
    None 
    if wordfreq == [] 
    else 
    [None, (w, c) = wordfreq[0], print(w, '-', c), wf_print(wordfreq[1:])][0]
)
```

But there is syntax error with the assignment in the list.

Could you point me in the right direction when it comes to both of these functions?

Comment: Why would someone completely new to python want to use a Y combinator lol. Take a look at [onelinerizer](https://github.com/csvoss/onelinerizer).

Comment: The Y combinator doesn't even *work* in Python - it requires normal-order evaluation, which Python doesn't use.

Comment: Why write as a lambda?

Comment: I can't see why you would *have* to use a lambda when you can simply use the name of a normal, named function...

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami It's part of my homework. But I guess if I used this onelinerizer, then converting that to Y or Z combinator would be even harder for me, right?

Comment: @user2357112 I guess the Z combinator would be a more precise term in that case.

Comment: @Tim It's part of my homework: "Remember, the goal of the Y combinator is to support recursion without explicitly referring to names of functions. So that's the constraint you need to honor here. Another way of specifying this is this: rewrite the program so that the recursive functions remain recursive but don't refer to themselves (or others) by name." So I guess I'd need lambdas in order not to refer to functions by name...

Comment: @Quentin: That assignment is saying that you can't have `count` or `wf_print` invoke `count` or `wf_print` by name. It's not saying that the functions aren't allowed to have names.

Comment: For example, the `count` in `count(word_list[1:], stopwords, wordfreqs)` in the body of `count` is forbidden. The `count` in `def count(word_list, stopwords, wordfreqs):` is fine.

Comment: @Quentin There is a youtube video of a talk about onelinerizer.

Comment: @user2357112 Okey, but I didn't know what this "(or others)" fragment meant. For example, does the second function in this form: `def wf_print(recfunc, wordfreq):
    if wordfreq == []:
        return
    else:
        (w, c) = wordfreq[0]
        print(w, '-', c)
        recfunc(recfunc, wordfreq[1:])` fulfills the requirements?